# OutOfMemoryException when writing PDFBox document to file / is writing on the fly possible?

Tags: java, pdf, out-of-memory, pdfbox

I'm generating PDF files from scanned image files. Every image is one page in the PDF file. Now there are documents with ~1000 pages (images). Java eats all the memory and gets an OutOfMemoryException.

Is there a way to write the PDFBox PDDocument like an OutputStream directly to the file. So when rendering page 10, page 1-9 are already saved to disk and the process only needs memory for the current page. Is this somehow possible? Or is there another way to handle the high memory usage?

Comment: Okay so what have you tried so far?

Comment: There's [this](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#PDDocument(org.apache.pdfbox.io.MemoryUsageSetting)) constructor for `PDDocument` which takes a [MemoryUsageSetting](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/io/MemoryUsageSetting.html) object which "*Controls how memory/temporary files are used for buffering streams etc.*", have you looked at that? Also [this](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#save(java.io.OutputStream)) method which saves it to an `OutputStream`.

Comment: The answer to the question is "no" but the second comment should help.

Comment: Yes, thanks, @Mark. This helped me. Now the conversion runs without memory problems.

Comment: @Michael Perfect, I'm curious, which one of the two options worked for you?

Comment: My bet is on MemoryUsageSetting.

Comment: save() is what I use. But it saves at the end. So yes, the solution is MemoryUsageSetting. Mark, if you write an answer with some code snippet, I could check your answer as accepted and you'll earn some reputation.